# How can I convert multiple Xpaths to a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xpath, web-scraping

I started a scrape for the 2018 MLB pitchers. I have various categories that I would like to turn into a dataframe so I can print to excel. I would like to use pandas. Here is my code at the moment:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-pitching.shtml"

#remove HTML comment markup
content = str(urlopen(url).read())
comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
tree = fromstring(comment)    

for pitcher_row in tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]'):
    names = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
    age = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="age"]/text()')[0]
    w = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="W"]/text()')[0]
    l = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="L"]/text()')[0]
    g = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="G"]/text()')[0]
    gs = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="GS"]/text()')[0]
    ip = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="IP"]/text()')[0]
    hits = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="H"]/text()')[0]
    runs = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="R"]/text()')[0]
    bb = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="BB"]/text()')[0]
    so = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="SO"]/text()')[0]

#print data        
    print(names, age, w, l, g, gs, ip, hits, runs, bb, so)
```

I would like to create one dataframe with my scrapes. Does anyone know how to do this?

I see an explanation on how to create a dataframe on https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html, however, I don't know how to apply it to my situation.

Here is an example below:

```
>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
```

I want to use my data above, though. Not sure if I need to append my data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about instantiating an empty dataframe and appending your scraped data rowwise:

```
columns = ("names", "age", "w", "l", "g", "gs", "ip", "hits", "runs", "bb", "so")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for idx, pitcher_row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]')):
    tmp = []
    tmp.append(pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text)
    tmp.append(pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="age"]/text()')[0])
    tmp.append(pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="W"]/text()')[0])
    ...

    df.loc[idx] = tmp
```

Or even simpler if you want to stick with most of your code:

```
columns = ("names", "age", "w", "l", "g", "gs", "ip", "hits", "runs", "bb", "so")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for idx, pitcher_row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]')):
    names = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
    age = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="age"]/text()')[0]
    w = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="W"]/text()')[0]
    l = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="L"]/text()')[0]
    g = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="G"]/text()')[0]
    gs = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="GS"]/text()')[0]
    ip = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="IP"]/text()')[0]
    hits = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="H"]/text()')[0]
    runs = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="R"]/text()')[0]
    bb = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="BB"]/text()')[0]
    so = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="SO"]/text()')[0]

    df.loc[idx] = (names, age, w, l, g, gs, ip, hits, runs, bb, so)
```

Comment: Your work is flawless @petezurich! Thank you so much sir for your time and effort, sir. Much appreciated =)